# Intersecting polygons from different layers based on common values using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, intersection, python-2.7

I have two polygon shapefiles (ShapeA and ShapeB) that share some areas. The shapefiles have one attribute in common (CODE) and I would like to do a selection, where I select all the polygons in one shapefile one by one and the corresponding polygon in the other shapefile based on same attribute value to get the intersection. Is this possible in some meaningful way using Arcpy?

[image: intersecting areas]

Comment: When you say "intersect" do you mean spatial intersect?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall, that's right, I want to spatially intersect say CODE_2 from ShapeA with CODE_2 from ShapeB. Does it make sense?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. Please also specify which GIS software stack you intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my workflow:

[Merge](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm) your two polygons together into a single feature class.

[Dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the merged feature class by field `CODE`. `multi_part` should be set to `SINGLE_PART`.

Comment: sorry for the delay, holidays in the middle. Thanks for this, that actually solved my query.